# Header won't stretch out to full page width

Tags: html, css

I have an image as a header and in the css I set the width at "100%" but it didn't go the full way so I tried "190%" and it only extending to the right hand side of the page. I then proceeded to change the height to % as it was in px and I wanted it in % to make it look neat as the width is % but then he image disappeared.

plus I can't even change position of the image.

Here is my problem: http(semi-colon)//prntscr.com/3ufy00

Here is my code:

**CSS**

```
body { }

#image {
width:100%;
height:178px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">

  <header id="menu">
<img id="image" src="http(semi)//oi62.tinypic.com/6t3fp2.jpg">
  </header>

</div>
```

Comment: Well 100% means it fills its parent so if your wrapper has any size restraints on it then it will only fill that size. Check out how it looks on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b8M79/) though. Seems to look ok with only the code you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this

```
add 

html,body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5r6ht/

Comment: Should of copied the code from fiddle, I am pretty sure your css in your answer will not work

Comment: explain please and did u check the fiddle

Comment: The fiddle I am sure works but the css in your answer is invalid due to typo `o` instead of `0`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a reset.css ? 
    body {margin:0; padding:0} try to put the img height to auto, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="wrapper">

  <header id="menu">
<img id="image" src="http(semi)//oi62.tinypic.com/6t3fp2.jpg" height="100">
  </header>

</div>
```

You can try like this also.

Answer (score 0):

If your wrapper has a restricted with then any full width elements will need to be outside of it

**HTML**

```
<header id="menu">
    <img id="image" src="http://oi62.tinypic.com/6t3fp2.jpg" />
</header>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#image {
    display: block;
}
.wrapper {
    max-width:80%;
    margin:0 auto;
    /* centered */
    height: 150px;
    /* just for show */
    background-color: gold;
}
```

**[JSfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LvK96/3/)**